# Dynamic URL with static routing in Express

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, routes

I want to statically render a page that uses a dynamic url in Express.

Specifically,

I have a forum where users make posts, and each post has a dynamic url that displays the post when a user clicks the associated anchor link:

```
localhost:8080/posts/postNumber
```

I have a static html page localhost:8080/posts/.

I want the dynamic links the user clicks to render the static page localhost:8080/posts/, but display the url localhost:8080/posts/postNumber, so that I can then use the post number with an AJAX request.

Is there any way to do this without dynamic rendering as I am trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define url parameters like this:

```
app.get('/posts/:postNumber/', function (req, res) {
   // do stuff (or not) with req.params which will have
   // {postNumer: yourValue}

    var options = {
        root: __dirname + '/public/',
        dotfiles: 'deny',
        headers: {
          'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
          // other headers you might want
        }
    };

    var fileName = 'staticFileName';
    res.sendFile(fileName, options, function (err) {
       if (err) {
         next(err);
       } else {
         console.log('Sent:', fileName);
       }
    })
})
```

This will match `/posts/[anything_you_want]` and send the filename specified its `fileName` in the directory specified in the options. This based on the express 4 docs here: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is statically rendering the page "/posts" but without app.request. I want the page /posts to render as if the user just went to /posts, but have the url still show up as dynamic

Comment: Sorry @mrybak3, I must be missing something — you can just render static HTML on the route. and then the user will see the same page regardless of what the put after `posts/`.

Comment: That's true. But what I will do is have a blank posts page, then get the postNumber via jquery from the url, and make an ajax call to retrieve information from the server and append it to the posts page. What you showed me works, but doesn't do it in the way I want it to.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. See the edit. You can specify the static file that you will be using and send it via Express's `sendFile()`. The route will always send the same page, and the URL will have the parameter info.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Just to be clear, sendFile() is rendering a page statically, correct?

Comment: Yeah, `sendFile()` just sends the file like a regular old web server.

Comment: if i add dynamic routes then i donot render CSS file